# How to writer query in Neo4j by java

Tags: networking, neo4j, cypher, friend

My data structure is:

```
Node node1 = graphDb.createNode();
node1.setProperty("id", "123");
Node node2 = graphDb.createNode();
node1.setProperty("id", "456");
Node node3 = graphDb.createNode();
node1.setProperty("id", "789");
node1.createRelationshipTo(node2, RelTypes.HASFOLLOW);
node1.createRelationshipTo(node3, RelTypes.HASFOLLOW);
node2.createRelationshipTo(node3, RelTypes.HASFOLLOW);
```

I want to query node1's followers (node2, node3) and query who is followed by node3 (node 1, node2).  
     `final ExecutionEngine engine = new ExecutionEngine(graphDb);
     ExecutionResult result = engine.execute("START n=node(*) RETURN n.id");`
How to write code like above?

Answer (score 2):

Sorry to say, this is a classic RTFM, see http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/query-create.html.